# Where does RetroPie save screenshots?

Tags: retropie

When using an lr-emulator in RetroPie, you can take a screenshot of the current game at any time by opening RGUI (Select+X) and selecting `Quick Menu → Take Screenshot`.

After taking a few screenshots, I can't figure out where they were saved. I've tried looking in `/home/pi/Pictures/` and `/home/pi/RetroPie/`, but I can't seem to find them.

**Where does RetroPie save screenshots by default?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this forum post](https://retropie.org.uk/forum/topic/13418/locating-my-screenshots), RetroPie's default screenshot folder is:

```
/opt/retropie/configs/all/retroarch/screenshots
```

Alternatively, there is a shortcut to this folder:

```
/home/pi/.config/retroarch/screenshots
```

The default screenshot directory can be changed in RGUI:

```
Main Menu -> Settings -> Directory -> Screenshot
```